# Return a promise in Pase.Query.each() don't work

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

On a Cloud Code Background Job I have one method for retrieving information from an API:

```
  var getUserPageView=function(userid){
    var promise=new Parse.Promise();
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'http://apiip.ch/api.php?date='+
        formatDate(new Date())
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        // success
        var text=httpResponse.text;
        var obj=JSON.parse(text);
        promise.resolve(parseInt(obj[0][1]));
    },function(httpResponse) {
        // error
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        promise.reject();
    });
    return promise;
};
```

For all the user I have to call the API for retrieving information about one specific user. 
According to the [specification of the "each()" function](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#each):

> If the callback returns a promise, the iteration will not continue until that promise has been fulfilled.

I return a promise that will be fulfilled when the API return the results.

```
query=new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.each(function(user){
    var promise=Parse.Promise().as();
    promise=promise.then(function(){
        getUserPageView(234).then(function(result){
            console.log("User page view:"+ result);
            //process user with API information
            promise.resolve("a");
        },function(){
            console.log("error");
        });
    });

    console.log("user processed");
    return promise;
}).then(function(){
    status.success("Credti update successfull.");
}, function(error){
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
});
```

The problem is that the getUserPageView() is never called. Or more precisely I think that the "each ()" function don't wait that the promise is fulfilled. What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for starters, `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`  already gives a promise, no need to wrap it:

```
var getUserPageView=function(userid){   // not sure why userid is required, it is not used anywhere.
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'http://apiip.ch/api.php?date='+ formatDate(new Date())
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {    // success            
        var text=httpResponse.text;
        var obj=JSON.parse(text);
        return parseInt(obj[0][1]);
    },function(httpResponse) {  // error            
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        throw httpResponse;
    });
};
```

as for the `query.each()` I am not really sure, just taking a blind stab at it:

```
query=new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.each(function(user){
    return getUserPageView(234).then(function(result){
        console.log("User page view:"+ result);  //process user with API information
    },function(){
        console.log("error");
    });        
}).then(function(){
    status.success("Credti update successfull.");
}, function(error){
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
});
```

Comment: Thanks you now I make it working with your advice. I had to add also a return  result on the getUserPageView().then() function. So:

return getUserPageView(234).then(function(result){
            console.log("User page view:"+ result);
            return result;
        },function(error){
            console.log("error");
        });

Answer (score 0):

@mido22 is exactly right about the first method.  Just return the promise returned by httpRequest.  To repeat, fixing his/her fix a little:

```
var getUserPageView=function(userid){
  return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: 'http://apiip.ch/api.php?date='+
      formatDate(new Date())
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
      // success
      var text=httpResponse.text;
      var obj=JSON.parse(text);
      return parseInt(obj[0][1]);
  },function(httpResponse) {
      // error
      console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
      return httpResponse;
  });
};
```

Regarding the second method, what's missing (at least) is a return value from the inner promise.  Parse.Promise.when makes the logic clearer, imo, taking an array of promises and fulfilling when all of them are fulfilled...

```
// very handy for iteration and much more
var _ = require('underscore');

query=new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.limit(4);  // start out with a small number to make sure it works (all users will eventually run afoul of resource limits)
query.find().then(function(users){
    var promises = _.map(users, function(user) {
        return getUserPageView(234);
    });
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}).then(function(){
    status.success(_.toArray(arguments));  // when() returns an array of results for each input promise, these are in var args of the success function
}, function(error){
    status.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice to add a return on the inner promise, I have missed this detail. I think that your code is also correct but I used the code from @mido22.

Comment: No need to explain SO checkmarks.  Please note for your project, though, that `throw` will just terminate, since there's no catch, leaving the caller with no info on an error (just the parse error that you didn't call success/error).  Also, the structure of the each code you selected denies the caller any positive or negative results besides a message.  This works for cloud *procedures* (where you only want a side effect), but not cloud *functions* where the caller expects data.